# Do immutable variables influence the contract bytecode?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, storage, bytecode, immutable

Suppose you have a contract like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.19;

contract Bar {
    uint256 public immutable value;

    constructor(uint256 value_) {
        value = value_;
    }
}
```

Will `Bar` have different bytecodes if different values are passed to the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `Bar`'s bytecode depends on `value_`, because [immutable variables are not part of contract storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/146828/24693).

We can prove this with the following [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh) test:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.19 <0.9.0;

import { PRBTest } from "@prb/test/PRBTest.sol";

import { Bar } from "src/Bar.sol";

contract BarTest is PRBTest {
    Bar internal bar0;
    Bar internal bar1;

    function setUp() public virtual {
        bar0 = new Bar(42);
        bar1 = new Bar(43);
    }

    // fails because the bytecodes don't match
    function test_Bytecode() external {
        bytes memory code0 = address(bar0).code;
        bytes memory code1 = address(bar1).code;
        assertEq(code0, code1, "bytecodes don't match");
    }
}
```

The bytecode of `bar1` will differ from that of `bar0` just by one character - in the 162nd position, `bar0` has `a`, whereas `bar1` has `b`.

```
// bar0
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80633fa4f24514602d575b600080fd5b60537f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a81565b60405190815260200160405180910390f3
```

```
// bar1
0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80633fa4f24514602d575b600080fd5b60537f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b81565b60405190815260200160405180910390f3
```

Comment: Don't `bar0` and `bar1` have different bytecode simply because of the different arguments passed to the constructor (and not because those arguments are used to initialize `immutable` contract members)? 